# Serializer Relations Doesn't Work in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models in my application. Here is my code in `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class TblDivision(models.Model):
    strdivisionname = models.CharField(db_column='strDivisionName', max_length=35, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Tbl_Division'

class TblPosition(models.Model):
    strpositionname = models.CharField(db_column='strPositionName', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Tbl_Position'

class TblEmployee(models.Model):
    strname = models.CharField(db_column='strName', max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    stremployeeid = models.CharField(db_column='strEmployeeID', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    bitactive = models.BooleanField(db_column='bitActive', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    intdivision = models.ForeignKey(TblDivision, db_column='intDivision',related_name='division', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    intposition = models.ForeignKey(TblPosition, db_column='intPosition',related_name='position', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Tbl_Employee'
```

This is my code in `serializer.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import TblEmployee,TblDivision

class DivisionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TblDivision
        fields=['id','strDivisionName']     


class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    division = DivisionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TblEmployee
        fields=['id','strname','stremployeeid','intdivision','division']
```

And this my `views.py`:

```
from .models import TblEmployee
from .serializer import EmployeeSerializer,DivisionSerializer

from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(["GET", ])

def api_list_employee_view(request):
    try:
        employee_list = TblEmployee.objects.all()
    except TblEmployee.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == "GET":
        serializer = EmployeeSerializer(employee_list, many="true") 
        dataEmployee = serializer.data
        return Response(dataEmployee)
```

I want to create a simple API that shows data from Employee model and its division name in JSON Format. But the API doesn't show the `strDivisionName` field. It shows only field from `Employee` model. Can Anyone explain my problem and its solution? I'm still new in Django Rest Framewrok. Thank you before

Comment: strdivisionname not strDivisionName

Answer (score 0):

Update your serializer with this code:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import TblEmployee,TblDivision

class DivisionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TblDivision
        fields=['id','strdivisionname']
```

In the fields, you showing the wrong field name. It's **strdivisionname** not **strDivisionName**.

Comment: I've already change it. But still doesn't show the strdvisionname.  Is something wrong with my views or models?. The relation between Employee and Dvision is One to One

Answer (score 0):

my friend you made a mistake in your serializer code! you must provide exact same name you entered in your models (in models you wrote : 'strdivisionname' and in serializer : 'strDivisionName')

Comment: Yes, I've already noticed my mistake. But the 'strdivisionname' still doesn't show in my API. It still shows from Employee fields only

Answer (score 0):

because you serialize your TblEmployee instance with EmployeeSerializer! and in your EmployeeSerializer there is not any strdivisionname fields! you must make a foreignKey from that in your models, am I right?